# IntelliJ: Suppress quote insertion for HTML attributes

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA 11 or 12, with an HTML file open, typing

```
<img src=
```

causes automatic insertion of double quotes, resulting in

```
<img src=""
```

Since I type ahead of where I read, this usually means I end up with something like

```
<img src=""image.png" alt="Image"/>"
```

**How do I prevent double-quotes from being inserted automatically after attribute names?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried it with IDEA 12 and double quotes are inserted only after you start completing `src` attribute and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or type `=` to confirm the completion. It doesn't happen automatically, you invoke completion that inserts quotes.

There is no option to control it, so you will have to break your habit to insert quotes manually and use <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead.

---

It's also possible to use the template completion with:

`img`<kbd>Tab</kbd> to generate `<img src="" alt="">` with the caret inside first pair quotes.
Then just enter the image file name, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, enter alt text.

You can always [submit a feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/WEB) to disable adding quotes on attributes completion.

Comment: This question is distinct from the "Automatically insert required attributes" setting.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Based on your observation, I've set Editor > Code Completion > Preselect the first suggestion to Never as a trial workaround. I'll see which is the greater evil.

Comment: In IDEA 13 File -> Settings -> Editor -> Smart Keys there is a setting "Automatically add quotes for attribute value".

Comment: Zook: Works perfectly. Thanks. Please post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 10):

In Intellij IDEA 14 and 15 (see @Zook's comment for IDEA 13), the option is now

Windows:

> Menu File→Settings→Editor→General→Smart Keys→Add quotes for attribute value on typing '=' and attribute completion (under XML/HTML section on the right side of the Settings dialog)

Mac:

> Preferences→Editor→General→Smart Keys→Add quotes for attribute value on typing '='

I don't know if it was the same for previous versions, but what actually happens in IDEA 14 is it automatically inserts both quotes and puts the cursor inside them. That's fine, but then when you type what *you expect to be* your opening double-quote, the smart punctuation mechanism thinks you're *closing* the quotes and skips you over the automatically-inserted close quote (the same as it does in e.g. java code when you type a closing parenthesis when it has already auto-inserted one). So you wind up with the cursor after the pair of quotes, typing your attribute value. This seems consistent with the original observation.

I would actually consider this a bug in IDEA but I guess the fact that opening and closing punctuation are the same symbol in this case makes things complicated. The smart punctuation mechanism would need to know to ignore the *first* quote you typed, but if you actually wanted to type an empty attribute value like `src=""`, it would need to ignore the first quote and then jump over the close quote for the second one. Fiddly, but not impossible.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you for this answer, as this was driving me crazy.  This works for IDEA 15 as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just change Input Language from "US - International" to "US". Switching to just "US" fixed the problem.

Read IntelliJ [thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000604050-Insert-pair-quote-not-working-properly-on-Mac-IDEA-Ultimate-2018-1-)